# How to get the id of the current model in Laravel when saving

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am working in a Laravel 5 application. I try to save a **comment** for a **projet** and I don't know how to get the **$comment->project_id** value.

Here is my simplified controller

```
public function store( CommentsFormRequest $request )
{
    $comment = new Note;
    $comment->message              = Input::get('message');
    $comment->project_id           = $note->project->id;
    $comment->user_id              = Auth::id();
    $comment->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

and here is my simplified form

```
  {!! Form::open(array('route' => 'notes.store')) !!}

    {!! Form::textarea('message', '', array('placeholder'=>'Message')) !!}

  {!! Form::submit('Ajouter la note') !!}
  {!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I try to save, I get this error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

I guess it's because it tries to get the sollicitation_id of the new object wich is null. How should I get the current project_id value?

**Update**

Conclusion: I used an hidden field and followed @tommy 's recommendation.
My controller now uses

```
$note->project_id  = $request->input('project_id');
```

and my hidden field is

```
{!! Form::hidden('project_id', $project->id ) !!}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the store method, you try to get the property `project` of the variable `$note`, which does not exist. You should pass the project ID to the store method by either adding it to the route or adding a hidden field `project_id` to your form.

Then, your store method should look something like this:

```php
public function store($project_id, CommentsFormRequest $request )
{
    $project = Project::find($project_id); // $project_id is transmitted over the URL

    $comment = new Note; // I'd alias Note as 'Comment', or rename '$comment' to '$note' because this can be confusing in the future
    $comment->project_id = $project->id;
    $comment->save();

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

If you want to add a hidden field with the project ID to the form, you can access its value by calling `$request->input('project_id');`

Comment: Just to note, you don't really have to fetch the whole project from the database (`$project = Project::find($project_id);`), but referring to your question, this should make things clear for you :-)

Comment: I follow your last note and created an hidden field. Then I get the value with = $request->input('project_id');

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 6):

Only IF the table primary column name is 'id':

```php
$model->id;
```

Regardless of primary column name:

```php
$model->getKey();
```

Comment: `getId()` was killing me too, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I feel the above answer is far from perfect as you're not only exposing Unique ID's to users but it's also long winded, and would fail if two users were to load the same page at the same time, instead you should do

```
public function store(CommentsFormRequest $request )
{
    $comment = new Note([
       // your fields here
    ]};
    $comment->save();
    //$comment now contains a unique ID!
    return redirect($comment->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can get last id by using insertGetId() Query Builder method**

> If the table has an auto-incrementing id, use the insertGetId method to insert a record and then retrieve the ID:

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

[for more info check document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries)